# How execute JS on XML AJAX request responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with selecting rows in table that i get from xml request.
Look for example below:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_database

My web is similar. Is there posible to use JS function that let me change background after click the row with defined class? I guess responseText doesn't return class name. 
Currently my JS function works everywhere but doesn't in DIV that display xml request.

order.php:

```
// -that is a part from page that connect with sql base. it is what is return to main page and it works.[for example 3 squares with orderd detail]
while($num!=0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo '<div class="order"><p id="data">Date:'.$row['Whens'].'</p><p id="types">'.$row['Types'].' '.$row['Brand'].'</p><br><p id="whats">'.$row['Whats'].' </p><br> <p id="detai"> '.$row['Detai'] .'</p></div>';
    $num--;
}
```

index.php:

```
// -this is a part from main page where I get data from order.php - it works.
function showUser(id){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
       document.getElementById("order_t").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","order.php?q="+id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

JS function

```
// - I try use below to change background in div's with class="order" which I get from order.php. It does't work
$(".order").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("selected2").siblings().removeClass("selected2");
})
```

Comment: Add you code please, so we can review it.

Comment: Done. Is it ok, now?

Comment: Is the JS executed after creating the `order` divs? I mean, first add the code that create the divs and then add the `$(".order").click` thingy.

Comment: First add $(".order").click after then add function showUser(id)

Comment: I tried a few other place where $(".order").click can be executed and nothing have changed. The function always work if i change class name to other existed class for other object. :<

Comment: Do `console.log()` inside your click function, to check if is actually called. Also do `console.log($(".order").length)` before appending the click event, to see if is actually selecting something.

Comment: Problem has been solved.  It had to changed boolean variable on false.
xmlhttp.open("GET","order.php?q="+id,true);